# Deploying on multiple platforms and architectures?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am the lead developer in a small business which is just starting. We are developing a cross platform C library which is intended to run on as wide an array of architectures and operating systems as possible. We have extensive unit tests, so if these tests pass on a new platform then we can say with a fair amount of certainty that the library works reliably on that platform.

Up until now, I have been using Windows 32 bit (which is my development machine), as well as a Linode VPS to make sure the library works under Linux with GCC. Now, I am looking to deploy for other platforms as well (namely more Linux distribution flavors, Mac OS X, and preferably some of the smartphones if at all possible). I want to avoid virtualizing all of these platforms if I can. Are there any services that will allow me to deploy the library on many operating systems and architectures? For all of the platforms I mentioned above, I would like to make both 32 and 64 bit builds available and also for different processors as needed. I would like to be able to build the library for all of these platforms, and run the unit tests. The unit tests are written using Boost.test.

Does anyone have any recommendations? The best way would be if there was some sort of convenient cross compiler for the various platforms that I could install on my Linode VPS (Ubuntu 13.04), but a third party solution to which I should upload the code would also work.

Comment: "Lead developer".... oohhhkay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only cross platform compile (which has a tradition, is free and has the support of a large community) is gcc. Of course, there is Intel Compiler and many others (and even the newer, free clang which seems to be used by llvm, but it is still young). You can find a good list here (for C++, but you can scroll on the page and find for any other language):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C.2B.2B_compilers

If you want to build for Mac from Linux please check this:

http://www.bpiwowar.net/2012/06/cross-compiling-for-os-x-with-distcc-on-linux/

And for windows from Linux:

[Manual for cross-compiling a C++ application from Linux to Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182408/manual-for-cross-compile-a-c-application-from-linux-to-windows)

Regarding the mobile platforms:

- for **Android**, there is native support for Linux/Windows/Mac so you can use any of these platforms to build apps for it
- for **Windows Phone**: Not so, maybe you manage to run Visual Studio using wine and then you're set, but otherwise there is no way that I know of. You can try CodeWeaver which is the "Wine for money" which seems to support Visual Studio 2008:

http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/company/?letter=m;company_sort%5Bcompany_name%5D=ASC;company_curPos=200;company_id=1;sort%5Bapp_name%5D=ASC;curPos=400

Furthermore, you can try this application to develop programs in .NET:

http://monodevelop.com/

- for **Iphone**: well, it is not straightforward but you can try this link:

http://www.saurik.com/id/4

I'm a Linux user myself, so the links above are "concentrated" on Linux as the primary dev system. Hope this helps! Good luck with your business!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I'll look through the provided links. I write my code on Windows, but I have access to a Linux VPS so I can certainly use that for cross compilation if it is simpler than Windows. For Windows Phone I'll just use my Windows box.