# gcc dll - compiled under Linux

Tags: gcc

I have a project written in gcc - bison -flex on Linux environment. All the project is implemented into a *.so file and is called from python-tkinter graphic surface.
 There is a need to run it on windows. However I'd avoid to install all the windows equivalent of gcc - bison -flex programs.
Is it possible to force gcc *IN LINUX ENVIRONMENT* to compile *WINDOWS DLL* instead of *.so? It could make life easier to use the same technics as I do now: just do calls from python-tkinter graphic surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, of course, cross-compile it.
You'll need some packages installed, though.
Your normal project would be able to build if you use the MINGW equivalent of GCC for the target architecture.
Also, take a look at this:
[Manual for cross-compiling a C++ application from Linux to Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182408/manual-for-cross-compile-a-c-application-from-linux-to-windows)
The linking can be kind of troublesome though, since it could come a time where softlinking fails due to versions. In that case you'll need to create some symbolic links to the correct version.
The output of the compilation process should be with -o DYNAMIC-LIBRARIE-NAME.dll and of course use the -shared flag.
Hope it gives you some pointers..
Regards.